# strange behavior with array assigment after forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
  var p = [2, 3, 6]
  var t=0
  var t1 = 1
  var t2 = 100
  var t3 = 200
  p.forEach(function () {})
  [t1, t2, t3] = [3, 4, 5]
```

Error looks like:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '200' of undefined

that seem very strange. Any option?

Update:

Purpose: test variables array assignment after foreach, this code just for test

Details:

1. after foreach if define new variable acquire [3,4,5] no problem. It just
   happend use [t1,t2,t3] that before foreach defined. It doesn't
   matter, whether foreach stop or not.
2. use for-loop everything fine

Thanks for your help. @Madison Courto I've tried, but why?

Comment: This code looks very strange. What are you trying to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's still trying to run the `forEach` loop.

If you were to do `p.forEach(function () {});` you'd stop it.

I don't understand the purpose though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and assume you wish to do something like this, regardless this will resolve the exception.

```
var p = [2, 3, 6];
var t = 0;
var t1 = 1;
var t2 = 100;
var t3 = 200;
p.forEach((number) => console.log(number));
p = [t1, t2, t3] = [3, 4, 5];
p.forEach((number) => console.log(number));
```

Comment: Yes! The t1 ,t2 and t3 are already defined. Why after foreach it needs a new define var before the array. Thanks.

Comment: Edited. I changed the value of "p" to demonstrate it's working. If you could be clear about what it you're trying to do we may be able to help further.